# Magento UI library dropdown

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to use the Magento UI Library "dropdown" element.

I've found an official (https://magento.com/developers/magento2) Magento 2 Demo at this [link](http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net) and going to the [dropdown docs](http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/docs/dropdowns.html) i've found that they are broken (i get no dropdown in chrome or firefox)

The documentations says that with this markup

```
<div class="example-dropdown-2">
    <span class="action toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true">
        <span>span + dropdown</span>
     </span>
     <ul class="dropdown">
         <li>
             <span class="item">One</span>
         </li>
         <li>
             <span class="item">Two</span>
         </li>
         <li>
             <span class="item">Three</span>
         </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

and with this less mixin

```
.example-dropdown-2 {
    .lib-dropdown();
}
```

it should work but as you can see it doesn't.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that you need to init the component with

```
 data-mage-init='{"dropdown":{}}'
```

so the html should be:

```
<div class="example-dropdown-2" data-mage-init='{"dropdown":{}}'>
<span class="action toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true">
        <span>span + dropdown</span>
     </span>
     <ul class="dropdown">
         <li>
             <span class="item">One</span>
         </li>
         <li>
             <span class="item">Two</span>
         </li>
         <li>
             <span class="item">Three</span>
         </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code instead (docs will be corrected soon):

```
   <div class="actions dropdown example-dropdown-2">
        <button class="action toggle"
                data-mage-init='{"dropdown":{}}'
                data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-haspopup="true">
            <span>button + dropdown</span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li>
                <span class="item">One</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="item">Two</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="item">Three</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is this so different from my answer? I've seen that you added the css class `actions` to the outer div but it doesn't seem to have any effect, right?

Comment: Also, in the  sample I provided `data-mage-init` is not in `<div>`

Comment: Yes, i tried but I see no difference when i load the page. I mean, in both cases i have a working dropdown